# Error Parsing JSON String to JSONObject in Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I have an application that stores this JSON String :

`String message ="{\"uid\":\"1\",\"streetName\":\"road\",\"city\":\"London\",\"speedLimit\":20}"`

Now I want to parse it back to a JSON Object, In order to do so I have this line:

```
    JsonObject object = new JsonParser().parse(message).getAsJsonObject();
```

I am using Gson Library to parse it and use it as a JSON Object. However, I am getting this exception :

```
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 1 column 2 path $.
```

***Update 1***

I have tried this

```
String message = "{"uid":"1","streetName":"road","city":"London","speedLimit":20}";
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(message);
```

Now I get this exception:

```
Unterminated string at character 28 of {"uid":"1","streetName":"roa
```

I have tried lots of workarounds from multiple threads on StackOverflow but nothing is working and I have no idea why ?

Comment: Where are all the backslashes from?

Comment: If that's a parser error, can you cross check that the error occurs just with the only line `JsonObject object = new JsonParser [...]` ? If that's the case, please delete the remaining code from the question by [edit]ing, since it's not relevant. It will help us understanding where the problem is. Such a reduced code is called an [MCVE].

Comment: Ok, great, now, that line `String message =` will certainly not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.

The String I was processing was malformed for the source. Fixing the string was the answer in here. Nothing was wrong with how I parsed the string.

Thanks for all the answers and the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can Directly cast it to the JSONObject,

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
String str =  "{\"uid\":\"1\",\"streetName\":\"road\",\"city\":\"London\",\"speedLimit\":20}";
response = new JSONObject(str);
```

Now the string response has casted as Json response.

Comment: Technically I'd not call that a "cast". A cast is `String str = (String) something;`

Comment: Can you explain why calling `parse()` fails but your code works? What's wrong when passing it to `parse()`?

Comment: Thanks but your solution results in "Missing value" Exception

Answer (score 0):

you code is fine and should work

please check on the import of the JsonParser in your java file (should be com.google.gson.JsonParser)

let know on the Gson version if the JsonParser is not the issue

Comment: Thanks...I checked the import and looks valid. I have also tried something else which is mentioned in Update 1.

Answer (score 0):

your code should work, may be you need to check the dependencies as mentioned before.

I am using this dependency `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0`

here is an sscce that work https://github.com/SalehAly/test-gson

[image: code]